# How to handling back event on previous fragment class

Tags: android, fragment

I want to change the string of characters on Title Bar when moving back
to previous fragment by calling "popBackStack function."
I want to change the string of characters on Title Bar on previous
fragment class. Can you tell me good way to do it?

Comment: here's little more information about the way I'm trying. I use TabHost on Fragment. And I setted other fragments as tab contents on the TabHost.

Comment: Then I think event methods(onCreateView, onResume Method...) are not called because I use frangment in fragment. I tried getClientFragmentManager function, but didn't work. Could you tell me how to make the event method being called under the circumstance above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to handle all events among the fragment is using the parent activity.
Use interface as described by android developer website.And you will find how to tackle that.

Answer (score 0):

There you can find the [life cycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) of fragments

I believe you can change any text in onCreateView and onResume Method.